# Raspberry Pi 3b+ error when display shows BLACK colour

Tags: display

I have a RPi 3b+, connected it via HDMI to several different TVs and a monitor via a HDMI to VGA adapter  (one at home, one at work ect). While using the adapter, after some hours the picture turned shortly to red and I had to reboot the Pi. Since then, the complete picture DISSAPEARS when a picure or a programm in BLACK! is opened, like the terminal window in full screen mode. It happens on each TV, Monitor ect. Sometimes the picture does not even turns on once. The only possibility is to use hdmi safe mode to make it working again. I tried every calibration in terms of hdmi modes but the problem remains.

Has anybody experienced such a behavior that the picture dissapears when something BLACK is on the screen ? What could this be, is this maybe a hardware damage caused by some voltage?

Searched all the web, but could not find any behavior like this.

Thank you for help!

Comment: Sounds like faulty HDMI to VGA adapter. What power supply are you using?

Comment: I use a 5v, 2.5A power supply. Not the original one, but never had any problems bevore with other Pi s with such a supply

Comment: and this problem appears via HDMI connection, no adapter used since then again

Comment: `I tried every calibration in terms of hdmi modes` ... what about `config_hdmi_boost` - have you tried that? Also, do you use the same HDMI cable with each device

Comment: Yes, I also tried all hdmi boost number, no change. Used always a different hdmi cable, every time the same problem. Looks like a hardware failure, isn't it?